# Public modifier not allowed in static block?

Tags: java

I have this:

```
public class Models {

  public static class User extends BaseModel {


    public static {

      public final TableField ID = new TableField("user_id", "userId");

      public final TableField HANDLE = new TableField("user_handle", "userHandle");

      public final TableField EMAIL = new TableField("user_email", "userEmail");

    }

  }

}
```

java says that public is not allowed as a modifier either before static in the "public static {}" block or in front of final. Does anyone know why? Perhaps I don't understand how a static block is different than declaring all 3 fields as `public final static`.

This is what I see:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

and this

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: yeah I misunderstood what static blocks were for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`public`, as an access modifier, cannot be applied to a block of code, and it cannot be applied to local variables inside a block of code either.

It seems that you just want to declare static final fields:

```
...
public static final TableField ID = new TableField("user_id", "userId");
...
```

No need to use a `static` block for that.

Answer (score 3):

There's a confusion on what this "static block" is. These are called `initializer blocks`, or in this case a `static initializer block`. For the former, the can be viewed as an extension to the constructor code which runs during initialization. In the latter case, they are run during the static initialization of the class (ie the first time the class is accessed).

These blocks are useful for setting up fields that may take multiple lines to execute, or to set up external resources.

```
public class Foobar {
    final static int FOO;
    // runs when first loading Foobar.class
    static {
        int i = 1;
        i += 2;
        FOO = i;
    }
    final int bar;
    // runs when first initializing new Foobar()
    {
        int j = 3;
        j += 4;
        bar = i;
    }
}
```

In general they are not very common, but one spot where they are particularly useful is for binding native JNI libraries. For example, this method ensures `foobar.dll` is loaded before the class is accessed.

```
public class FoobarJNI {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("foobar"); 
    }

    private native void foo();
    private native void bar();
}
```

Comment: yeah, I suppose for backward compatibility they didn't want to introduce another keyword, so they reused static - but ideally would've have used a different keyword

Comment: @AlexanderMills not quite sure what you mean here? `static` is placed in front to distinguish the normal instance initializer block from the static context. ie `class Foo 
{ static { ... } }` vs just `class Foo{ { ... } }`. Initializer blocks are fairly unique feature to Java compared to other languages so I can see how it might look awkward.

Comment: the static (and final) keywords are used in more than one context, because of this, users get confused. what I am saying is that instead of `static {}` they should have used a different keyword, eg  `initialize {}`, not sure how you didn't get that the first time I said it, but nbd

Comment: @AlexanderMills Ah I do see what you mean now. Not adding say `initialize` as a keyword to avoid compiling issues for legacy code. By the way, you should read up on the initializer blocks if you do use them. There are a few gotchas, especially for the static case, that can make your code act somewhat unexpectedly. This tutorial looks like it would be useful for you http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/21/initialization-blocks-constructors-and-their-order-of-execution/